# Pass and use option in cron job (Task Scheduling) - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I have cron job which I am calling manually in some of controller actions:

```
    $create= (bool) $request->get('create');

    $command = 'my_task';
    if($create){
        $command .= ' --create';
    }
    Artisan::call($command);
```

, but I want to pass and use that option in `handle` method in `MyTask` - `Console/Command/MyCommand.php`:

```
public function handle(){
    // get create option, do some work
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can dispatch the `$command` variable to the job by writing `MyTask::dispatch($command)`. Then the `$command` is available in the `handle($command)` method as parameter and you can call the Artisan command in the Job.